# How can I clear the pushpins from dynamically created MapLayers on a Bing Map?

Tags: c#, dynamic, bing-maps

I have this code:

```
DataLayer.Children.Clear();
```

...which removes the pushpins from the design-time MapLayer, declared like this:

```
<bm:Map Credentials="CuellarDobsonMcNallyPalmer420s" x:Name="photraxMap" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
    <bm:Map.Children>
        <!-- Data Layer-->
        <bm:MapLayer Name="DataLayer"/>
        . . .
```

But I also create additional MapLayers programmatically:

```
MapLayer mapLayerToUse = DataLayer;
if (Cre8DynamicMapLayer)
{
    mapLayerToUse = new MapLayer();
    mapLayerToUse.Name = String.Empty;
    photraxMap.Children.Insert(0, mapLayerToUse);
}
```

...so how can I also clear any of these dynamically created MapLayers?

I could do something involved such as give the dynamic map layers randomized names, store them in a list, and then iterate over that list, calling Children.Clear on them (after finding a MapLayer with that name), but I imagine there must be a simpler and more elegant way than that. Does anybody know of one?

### UPDATE

Nicolas, is something like this:

```
// App.xaml.cs
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public static List<MapLayer> dynamicMapLayers  { get; set; } 

    . . .

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
     . . .
        dynamicMapLayers = new List<MapLayer>();

//MainPage.xaml.cs (update of previously shown code):
MapLayer mapLayerToUse = DataLayer;
if (Cre8DynamicMapLayer)
{
    mapLayerToUse = new MapLayer();
    mapLayerToUse.Name = String.Empty;
    dynamicMapLayers.Add(mapLayerToUse); // <= this is the new line
    photraxMap.Children.Insert(0, mapLayerToUse);
}

// Finally, insted of doing all that looping as shown in my proposed answer, simply do this instead:
foreach (MapLayer ml in dynamicMapLayers)
{
    ml.Children.Clear();
}
```

...what you had in mind?

Comment: If you keep the reference to the MapLayer you created in a global context (let say in a global variable or your current view), then you don't need to iterate through each layer like you explained in your answer. You will just have to call the variable to clear the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did map.Children.Clear it would remove all MapLayers on the map, including the dynamically added ones. If you want to clear each MapLayer, without removing it, then you have to recursively loop through all the items in the MapLayer and check to see an item is a MapLayer or not as MapLayers can have child MapLayers. If an item is not a MapLayer then remove it, if it is, then recursively go through the child MapLayer.

Comment: Thanks, "Bing Maps Whisperer"; I'll probably go with the former.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping there would be something very concise and pithy, but it may be that I have to do something like this after all:

```
// Adapted the following from http://www.codeease.com/only-remove-pushpins-from-a-layer-in-bing-map.html
private void ClearPushpins()
{
    List<UIElement> elementsToRemove = new List<UIElement>();
    List<UIElement> pushpinToRemove = new List<UIElement>();
    foreach (String photoset in App.CurrentlyMappedPhotosets)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in photraxMap.Children)
        {
            if (element.GetType() == typeof(MapLayer))
            {
                MapLayer Lay = (MapLayer)element;
                if (Lay.Name == photoset)
                {
                    foreach (UIElement p in Lay.Children)
                    {
                        if (p.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin))
                        {
                            pushpinToRemove.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (UIElement pin in pushpinToRemove)
                    {
                        Lay.Children.Remove(pin);

                    }
                    elementsToRemove.Add(Lay);
                }
            }
            foreach (UIElement e in elementsToRemove)
            {
                photraxMap.Children.Remove(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete map layers by using the remove at function

```
   int number_of_layers = map.Layers.Count;        
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_layers; i++)
                {
                    map.Layers.RemoveAt(0);
                }
```